# Unable to put data in table element. No such element found error pop up

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Trying to send data in table element (cell). Verified ID, Xpath, CssSelector and none them is wrong.Even, put timeout till page load. Even verified the iFrame (Already switchTo current iFrame).

No such element found error pops up every time. Not sure if I need to switchTo iFrame again after page load?

I tried all the possible ways but not pass through. I really appreciate any suggestions or new direction to think.

Thank you in advance.

Run my script for better insight where its failing.

```
public class SapDijon 
{

    WebDriver driver;
    JavascriptExecutor jse;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
    {
        SapDijon sapObj = new SapDijon();

        sapObj.invokeBrowser();
        sapObj.initializeSapDijon();
        sapObj.ForecastME59();

    }//End of Main

    public void invokeBrowser()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "U:\\Research Paper\\Selenium\\Drivers\\Chrome\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }


    public void initializeSapDijon() throws Exception
    {
        Thread.sleep(1200);
        driver.get("http://dijon.cob.csuchico.edu:8041/sap/bc/gui/sap/its/webgui/?");
        driver.findElement(By.id("sap-user")).sendKeys("H5");
        Thread.sleep(1200);

        driver.findElement(By.id("sap-password")).sendKeys("Onsjhjsa1087");
        Thread.sleep(1200);

        driver.findElement(By.id("sap-client")).clear();
        Thread.sleep(1200);

        driver.findElement(By.id("sap-client")).sendKeys("485");
        Thread.sleep(1200);

        driver.findElement(By.id("LOGON_BUTTON")).click();
    }

    public void ForecastME59() throws InterruptedException
    {

        driver.switchTo().frame("ITSFRAME1");
        Thread.sleep(800);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='tree#105#4#1']//span[@class='lsSTStatusImg lsMirrorRtl lsSTStatusIcon urSTExpClo urCursorClickable']")).click();

        Thread.sleep(800);
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement md61 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='tree#105#6#1#1#i']"));
        action.doubleClick(md61).perform();

        driver.findElement(By.id("M0:46:::4:2-imgSymb")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("M0:46:::4:26")).sendKeys("HH-F");
        driver.findElement(By.id("M0:50::btn[0]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(6000);

        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='tbl5732[1,8]_c-r']/input[@id='tbl5732[1,8]_c']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='tbl5732[1,8]_c-r']/input[@id='tbl5732[1,8]_c']")).sendKeys("100");

    }
}//End of Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue persists because of a new window opened and the script was unable to find the element. The solution is to switch to a newly opened window to find element locator.

ArrayList tabs = new ArrayList (driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1));

Answer (score 0):

After " `action.doubleClick(md61).perform()`" switch back from frame to default content and again switch to the available iframe.

To move back to the parent frame, you can either use `switchTo().parentFrame()` or if you want to get back to the main (or most parent) frame, you can use `switchTo().defaultContent();`

Comment: I tried to navigate to parent frame and switch back to child iFrame. Still issue not resolved. Facing the same error - No such element found.